# How do I save data to a struct and then update the values in 2 different views?

Tags: swift, struct, swiftui

I know there is a way to do it by making my struct into a class, then by using ObservableObject, @ObservedObject, and @StateObject, but then I cannot keep a variable computed property connecting the data to instances of my main struct.
In my first view, I am able to change the data through a @State private var, but I can't figure out a way to update this into the data variable to use it on a different view.

My struct is inside of an extension of a different struct:

```
struct StudentClass: Identifiable {
    let id: UUID
    let title: String
    let teacher: String
    var grade: Float
    var theme: Theme
    var assignments: [Assignment]
    
    init(id: UUID = UUID(), title: String, teacher: String, grade: Float, theme: Theme, assignments: [Assignment]) {
        self.id = id
        self.title = title
        self.teacher = teacher
        self.grade = grade
        self.theme = theme
        self.assignments = assignments
    }
}
...
extension StudentClass {
...
    struct Data {
        var title: String = ""
        var theme: Theme = .seafoam
    }
    
    var data: Data {
        Data(title: title, theme: theme)
    }
```

Here is my view's main code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct EditView: View {
    @State private var data = StudentClass.Data()
    let classes: StudentClass
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            Section(header: Text("Class Info")) {
                TextField("Rename Class", text: $data.title)
                ...
                ThemePicker(selection: $data.theme)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and see: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  `PreviewProvider` is not needed ever, but you left our most of your implementation of `StudentClass`. You need to cut your code to the bare essentials to show the problem you are having.

Comment: @Yrb I cut my code down more and I included more of the StudentClass implementation. Can you explain how to save the data to my Data struct?

Comment: Please make sure you read How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example. Someone should be able to copy your code, paste it into a new project and run it to some extent, or come up with the same error that you are seeing if the question is about an error. Now, that being said, what is the point of `Data` in your extension? If you haven't already, please go through [Apple's SwiftUI Tutorials](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui) and I would also audit [Stanford's CS193P](https://cs193p.sites.stanford.edu). I think you are confused as to how to make a data model, and that is the issue.

Comment: I am trying to use Data in my extension to store a user's choice of theme and title for each of their classes. I am using the var data to store these choices for each instance of a StudentClass

Comment: But you ALREADY store those variables in the struct. You don't need a separate struct within the struct to store it again. You have two separate variables for each: `StudentClass.title` AND `StudentClass.Data.title` putting a string into one, does not put the string in the other. That is why I suggested the tutorial as Apple shows you how to set up your model, but essentially, your extension makes this worse.